# JMockit - warning when mocking methods that expect Collections

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

Is there a way to get the following mock to work without an Unchecked cast warning:

```
new Expectations() {{
        UrlService.addUrls((List<String>)any); result = expectedCandidates; 
}};
```

The `UrlService.addUrls()` method's signature is:

```
static List<Candidate> addUrls(List<String> urls)
```

Comment: cant you use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Comment: Obviously I can, but that would make me sad, and is generally a bad habit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best alternative is to use the `T witnAny(T arg)` argument matcher:

```
new Expectations() {{
    UrlService.addUrls(withAny(new ArrayList<String>()));
    result = expectedCandidates;
}};
```

Or, to disable the code inspection locally, if your IDE supports it. With IntelliJ, I can write:

```
new Expectations() {{
    //noinspection unchecked
    UrlService.addUrls((List<String>) any);
    result = expectedCandidates;
}};
```

... which really is OK. Code inspections are good and all, but there are always exceptional situations where it's fine to disable them.

Comment: OK, that really makes the warning go away but the expectation still doesn't work. The SUT returns an empty list instead of expectedCandidates, which was initialized earlier with some real data.

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot to include `result = expectedCandidates` (or whatever the desired result is).

Comment: I figured that part by myself. I meant that it returned an empty list when result = expectedCandidates was intact (when using the first warning-less approach).

Comment: It works fine for me, if I write a complete example test. Could you show a failing test?

Comment: I wrote a separate test and it worked for me as well, so I guess it's something else that I didn't notice along the way. I eventually chose to SuppressWarnings for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new Expectations() {
        {
            UrlService.addUrls(withArgThat(new IsAnything<List<String>>())); result = expectedCandidates;
        }
    };
```

Comment: OK, that works but I actually put some general code in the question instead of my real code for simplicity's sake. I edited the question with my real code, for which your fix still doesn't work. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: new IsAnything doesn't seem to be a thing that my compiler can recognize

Comment: It's a Hamcrest Core class:
org.hamcrest.core.IsAnything

Comment: OK, that works but it's very cumbersome. I'll mark it as accepted in a few hours if no better solution is presented. 10x